# Querying audio files from external storage on Android in Kotlin not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to query all audio files from the Music directory on an Android device.
For some reason however I do not get any and I do not know why.

This is the main activity I am trying to get the audio list in:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import com.example.musicplayer.Song
import com.example.musicplayer.components.activities.MainActivityScreen


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val audioList = querySongData(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, applicationContext)

        setContent {

        }
    }

    private fun querySongData(uri: Uri, context: Context) : List<Song> {
        val audioCursor = context.contentResolver
            .query(
                uri,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
            )

        val files = mutableListOf<Song>()
        if (audioCursor != null && audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val audioTitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
                val audioArtist = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
                val audioDuration = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
                val audioUri = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
                files.add(
                    Song(
                        title = audioCursor.getString(audioTitle),
                        artist = audioCursor.getString(audioArtist),
                        lengthInSeconds = audioCursor.getInt(audioDuration),
                        image = Uri.parse(audioCursor.getString(audioUri)),
                    )
                )
            } while (audioCursor.moveToNext())
        }
        audioCursor?.close()
        return files
    }

}
```

This is my simple Song data class:

```
data class Song(
    val title : String,
    val artist : String,
    val image : Uri,
    val lengthInSeconds : Int
    )
```

When using `MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` instead of `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` I at least get all the ring and alarm tones, but not the audio files I want to get.
The files are located at 'storage/emulated/0/Music' and are both .mp3-files.

I also tried declaring the projection, selection and sortOrder beforehand like this:

```
val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
        )
val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC} != 0"
val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE} ASC"
val audioCursor = context.contentResolver
            .query(
                uri,
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                sortOrder
            )
```

I also tried setting permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However all without success.

Thanks for the help!

```
13:16:37.671  D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
13:16:37.671  D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
13:16:37.686  D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
13:16:37.687  D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
13:16:37.688  D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
13:16:37.710  I  START
13:16:37.724  I  END
13:16:37.771  D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xec1ad260, tid 11244
13:16:37.775  D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
13:16:37.778  D  eglCreateContext: 0xec1adab0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
13:16:37.778  D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xec1adab0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xec4f6e50) (first time)
13:16:37.791  I  mapper 4.x is not supported
13:16:37.817  D  createUnique: call
13:16:37.817  D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xec1ad880, tid 11244
13:16:37.817  D  allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
13:16:37.817  D  allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f7ffe000 size 0x2000
13:16:37.849  D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
13:16:39.271  W  A resource failed to call close. 
13:16:43.562  D  Installing profile for com.example.musicplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android 30+ device then you should try this

```
val projection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
)
val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC} != 0 AND ${MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH} LIKE '%/Music/%'"
val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE} ASC"
val audioCursor = context.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    selection,
    null,
    sortOrder
)
```

here

> MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH

used for Scoped Storage:

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me :/.
But I am using a Android 30+ device so if this is really necessary it would make sense to include it. I tried now launching the app on my phone which is 33, but still the same result. Maybe I have to ask for Permissions?

Comment: there must be some error log so could you add it to the question it will we very helpful to understand actual problem

Comment: I added the log. However I do not get any errors. The code should get executed between the "START" and "END" log entry. Before this I get a lot of these types of warnings: `13:16:37.319  W  Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/internal/util/IndentingPrintWriter;->increaseIndent()Lcom/android/internal/util/IndentingPrintWriter; (greylist, linking, allowed)`
`13:16:37.319  W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mLoadedApkAssets:Landroid/util/LruCache; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)`
Dont know if they got anything to do with that.